# Cypress intercept, traverse and assert REST API response against UI elements

Tags: cypress

I am trying to validate the API response data against my UI but I am having issues while traversing into the JSON response.

The scenario goes like this:

#1 Click a button that triggers a REST call *//returns the below response/array of json* objects

```
[
  {
    "id": "Spain 1",
    "content": "77842B03FF9DE970C1256E520058DFFE\nSpain 1 \n",
    "lastUpdatedAt": "2021-05-24T06:50:00Z",
  },
  {
    "id": "Spain 2",
    "content": "9DED7F8F2CE195C7C125740C00366F52\nSpain 2 \n",
    "lastUpdatedAt": "2021-05-24T06:48:00Z",
  },
  {
    "id": "Spain 3",
    "content": "7D2C1C4E881560F3C1256E520058E01E\nSpain 3 \n",
    "lastUpdatedAt": "2021-05-24T06:46:00Z",
  }
]
```

#2 In the UI, I have a dropdown with x number of dropdown options depend on the above response's size. Since it has 3 JSON objects inside the array, the dropdown will have 3 options [`Spain 1, Spain 2, Spain 3`].

#3 Selecting dropdown option, will display the response .content in UI element (`'.ui-content'`)
E.g: Drodown value: `Spain 1` will render `77842B03FF9DE970C1256E520058DFFE\nSpain 1 \n` in UI element

#4 Iterate for all dropdown options [Spain 1 to 3] to validate the appropriate content.

So far, I have written the following code, but I am not able to traverse thru JSON values that block me to develop further validations against UI elements.

```
cy.wait('@portmemo').its('response.statusCode').should("eq", 200); //Passes
  cy.get('@portmemo').its('response')
    .then((response) => {
      // cy.log(response.body);//prints all body
      cy.log(response.body[0].id); //prints blank
      cy.log(response.body[0].lastUpdatedAt); //prints blank
      cy.log(response.body[0].content);//prints blank
      // cy.get('.ui-content').should('have.text', response.body[0].content);
    })
```

also tried with "`cy.get('@portmemo').its('response.body')`" but no luck. Is the `'response'` inside `then` not recognized as JSON object itself? or what am I missing?

Comment: What is `console.log(response.headers['content-type'])`? It should be `application/json; charset=utf-8`.

Comment: Very valid point @Sarah, it is giving `text/plain; charset=utf-8`. So, it is not a JSON format. I will parse it and add a complete solution soon.

Comment: I think you need to chain `.then(response => response.json())`, please see the answer I previously deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it using the `.json()` method,

```js
cy.wait('@portmemo').its('response.statusCode').should("eq", 200);
cy.get('@portmemo')
  .its('response')                      
  .then(response => response.json())   
  .then(json => {
    cy.log(json[0].id); 
    cy.log(json[0].lastUpdatedAt); 
    cy.log(json[0].content);
    cy.get('.ui-content')
      .eq(0)
      .should('have.text', json[0].content);
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Sarah, your comment really helped, I made it work.

Adding an additional answer with more details.

```
cy.get('@portmemo').its('response.body')
    .then((response) => {
     // If the response's content-type is text/plain then convert to JSON format first           
      var json = JSON.parse(response);
      cy.log(json.length)//3
      for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        cy.log(json[i].id)
        CurrentSchedule.selectBerthDropdown(json[i].id);
        CurrentSchedule.verifyPortMemoDetailsInPopUp(json[i].content);
      }
   })
```